# dynamic memory in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic

```
int a = 5;
int **b = new int*;
*b = &a;
**b = a + 6;
int *c = new int(**b);
```

I know b is a pointer and is pointing to a pointer, which will be allocated at run-time on the heap. 
`new int` returns a pointer, but what is `new int(**b)` ?Where is c pointing to?
This complex declaration is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

It's equivalent to:

```
int *c = new int(11);
```

The value that `c` points is initialized to `11`, which is the value of `**b`.

Comment: Was just about to type the same :D

Comment: Except that it's 11 in this case, not 42.

Comment: Yeah, I said it's *similar to*, not *equivalent to*, love using `42` in examples.

Comment: "It's equivalent of `int *c = new int(11);` because `**b` equals `11`" sound a little bit more clear

Comment: Sure, since you all think so, no problem for me.